# Unity objects disabled in hierarchy when I open my project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I worked on my project during months. Today when I open my project, some objects are disabled (inactive) on my hierarchy.

I have to click them and check the box in the inspector to make them active.

I tried to save my scene and my project then exit Unity. Then relaunch Unity.

But that doesn't work, the objects are still inactive at start.

How can I make them active again? I don't understand what is happening.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your scene? Are there any errors in the properties of the object? Does anything appear in the console when you start up the project? This problem is a bit too light on details to diagnose right now...

Comment: if i launch my project before enabling the disabled components, Unity crash.
No error on console , just the objects that are disabled after i load. Never happened before. Even if i enable then save, wont work
https://s27.postimg.org/x832bnhxf/unity.png

Comment: In the future, put your project in source control so you can compare revisions to find what changed. Or, as a last resort, revert to a working version.

Comment: I used a old .rar (backup). I will look for source control, never used it before. Thanks.